# Bash script to wget url starting with a specific character

Tags: bash, wildcard, wget

I have a URL `http://example.com/dir` that has many subdirectories with files that I want to save. Because its size is very big I want to break this operation in parts

eg. download everything from subdirectories starting with A like

```
http://example.com/A
http://example.com/Aa
http://example.com/Ab
etc
```

I have created the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

for g in A B C

do  wget -e robots=off -r -nc -np -R "index.html*" http://example.com/$g

done
```

but it tries to download only `http://example.com/A` and not `http://example.com/A*`

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't provide any way to list the files in a directory, so there's no way for `wget` to find all files beginning with a character. Do you have FTP access to the server? Then you can use `"ftp://example.com/path/to/webroot/$g*"`

Comment: Is there an index page that lists all files, or does `wget` have to discover them by following links between pages? If it has to follow links, it generally won't discover pages in alphabetical order, so trying to download them in that order won't work. You might be able to do something like this by setting a download quota (something like `-Q100k`), but I haven't experimented with that.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page, it has all you need to know:

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

**1)** You could use:

`--spider -nd -r -o outputfile <domain>`

which does not download the files, it just checks if they are there.
`-nd` prevents wget from creating directories locally
`-r`  to parse entire site
`-o outputfile` to send the output to a file

to get a list of URLs to download.

**2)** then parse the outputfile to extract the files, and create smaller lists of links you want to download.

**3)** then use `-i file` (== `--input-file=file`) to download each list, thus limiting how many you download in one execution of `wget`.

Notes:
- `--limit-rate=amount` can be used to slow down downloads, to spare your Internet link!